# How to find the convolution matrix?

Tags: image-processing, matrix, convolution

A isthe kernel and B is an image. How do you find a convolution matrix out of this equation?

A(x,y) = B(x,y) + 4B(x+1,y-1) + 2B(x,y+1) + 5B(x-1,y)

And directions are as below

```
 (x-1,y-1)  (x-1,y)  (x-1,y+1)
 (x,y-1)    (x,y)    (x,y+1)
 (x+1,y-1)  (x+1,y)    (x+1,y+1)
```

is the matrix below?

```
 0 5 0
 0 1 2
 4 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define your pixel coordinates. If the origin is at the right (!) bottom of the image, `x` runs from bottom to top and `y` from right to left, your matrix is correct. However this is quite an uncommon choice.

If your origin is at the bottom left, `x` runs from left to right and `y` runs from bottom to top, the matrix would be:

```
4 0 0
0 1 5
0 2 0
```

Note that the directions are inverted: For example, the matrix coefficient on the right of the center is applied to the picel on the left.

By the way, it is not correct that `A` is the kernel for arbitrary `B`. This is only the case for `B[0,0] == 1` and `B[x,y] == 0` for all other values of `x` and `y`.

**Update:**
So your `x` runs from top to bottom and your `y` from left to right. Then the convolution matrix is:

```
0 0 4
2 1 0
0 5 0
```

Comment: Origin is at the center of the image

Comment: Actually the origin position is not important. It's the directions that matter.

Comment: Updated the question